# InputType doesn't work when text is set with setText

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-inputtype

I have set `android:inputType="text|textCapWords"` to my EditText. When I type something in the field, the first letter is correctly capitalised, but if I set a full capitalised (or full lowercase) text using the `setText()` method, the text remains fully capitalised (or in lowercase).

How can I use setText for the text to comply with the input type?

Comment: This is expected behavior. You have to format the text yourself before using the setText() method.

Comment: This is what I thought. But is it possible to format the text automatically by getting the InputType set on the EditText?

Comment: I don't think it's possible in the default implementation. You could extend the EditText view and override the setText() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Amarok suggests

> This is expected behavior. You have to format the text yourself before
>   using the setText() method

But if you want to format your text just like `android:inputType="text|textCapWords` you can use the following method:

```
public static String modifiedLowerCase(String str){
        String[] strArray = str.split(" ");
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (String s : strArray) {
            String cap = s.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + s.substring(1).toLowerCase();
            builder.append(cap + " ");
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }
```

and use it like

```
textView.setText(modifiedLowerCase("hEllo worLd"));
```

It will convert it like :

**Hello World**

Answer (score 0):

You can check for your editText Type constants, and add simple `.toUpperCase()` to the text you're adding, like this:

```
if(mEditText.getInputType() ==  TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_CHARACTERS+ TYPE_CLASS_TEXT)
        mEditText.setText("Some text".toUpperCase());
    else
        mEditText.setText("some text");
```

More for input types constants [can be found here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
EditText.getText().clear(); 
EditText.getText().append("test");
```

rather than

```
EditText.setText("test");
```

so that the text that has been set follows the input type behavior

Comment: I tried on Android 9 (Pie) on a Samsung S8, in Kotlin. It doesn't work, the text remains in lower case.